# Does vm in Azure container cost?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Does VM in azure container service cost? Microsoft is saying that the AKS azure container service is free for students. But when I go to create container service it's give a pricelist with vm. Is it will be cost for me as I am a student subscriber?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Container Service is always free for a student subscriber, including it to cluster virtual machines.

[image]

[image]

But you should make sure that you haven't exhaust your available credit or reach the end of 12 months.You can see your remaining credit on the [Microsoft Azure Sponsorships portal](https://www.microsoftazuresponsorships.com/).

For more details, please refer to this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/free-account-students-faq/).

> **What happens after I use my $100 credit or I’m at the end of 12 months?**
>
> After you exhaust your available credit or reach the end of 12 months, your Azure subscription will be disabled. To continue using Azure, you may upgrade to a Pay-As-You-Go subscription by contacting Azure Support.